Must the nested-instructions's accounts be passed in, as well?
Does the accounts field of a program's Instruction include just the accounts the instruction needs/touches directly - or those that are required by the nested instructions called by it, as well?
It seemed natural for just the accounts touched directly to have to be passed to an instruction, until I stumbled upon the following paragraph in the documentation on Cross Program Invocation:

The runtime uses the privileges granted to the caller program to determine what privileges can be extended to the callee. Privileges in this context refer to signers and writable accounts. For example, if the instruction the caller is processing contains a signer or writable account, then the caller can invoke an instruction that also contains that signer and/or writable account.

So, which one is it?

I don't think there is a contradiction.
If your instruction, say ix1 makes a CPI call to another program via ixb then, you will pass in all accounts required in both the two ix's in your transaction.
This doesn't mean separate accounts for each instruction. If both instructions make use of say accountA, you'll only pass one instance of this account in your tx.
The signer escalation means that if you are making a cpi call, you can pass along the signer and writable permissions to the instruction being CPI'd into.
perhaps an example would be more helpful.
Shameless plug, Here is the ix from the bid program making a cpi call into the list program call the buy instruction.

Let's make the example even more specific.
Say we have a program currently executing an instruction - and want to invoke - from another program - an instruction ix1 which touches an address a and CPIs into another program's ix2 instruction, which touches an address b.
Must we pass both a and b when invoking ix1 from our program, even though ix1 doesn't touch b directly/itself?

Yes. It's like calling the transaction directly, only from within the program. Why is the account needed, the runtime needs to know all accounts it will interact with even if you aren't mutating anything in it.

Thank you for the clarification, @Jimii!
